# Right-floated div blocked by another div on a different line

Tags: html, css, web

[image: Problem]

I'm currently having trouble floating a textbox to the right-most side of it's parent div. I believe the problem lies with an element on the previous line. I know I could get this to work by floating 2 columns, one to the left and one to the right - opposed to floating each text element to the left and each input to the right. Simply inserting another line below the 'Reset Password' button works, but I don't like this solution. Out of curiosity, is there another solution to get the employee checkbox floated correctly to the right? Perhaps there is a way in CSS to have the employee textbox ignore the 'Reset Password' box?

Comment: Can you please post code as well , because I think the problem lies with the ordering of your elements . Also read the guidelines , on How to post a question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `clear:both;`.

First make the **Reset Password** float right, then make the **Permission Level** float left, but give it a `clear:both;` so it can float on a new line and ignore **Reset Password**, then when you float right the **Employee**, it will be floated the way you like.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5hG/)

Comment: This worked! Well actually `clear:right` worked while `clear:both` displayed the permission box on a new line. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Ali.